# Select most recent record (with expiration date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, duplicates

Let's say that we have 2 tables named Records and Opportunities:

Records:

| RecordID | CustomerID | CreateDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 777 | 1 | 1/1/2021 |
| 888 | 2 | 1/1/2021 |
| 999 | 1 | 2/1/2021 |

Opportunities:

| OppID | CustomerID | OppCreateDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 12/31/2020 |
| 11 | 1 | 1/10/2021 |
| 12 | 2 | 2/1/2021 |
| 13 | 1 | 4/1/2021 |
| 14 | 1 | 8/5/2025 |

Desired Output:

| RecordID | CustomerID | CreateDate | #Opportunities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 777 | 1 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 888 | 2 | 1/1/2021 | 1 |
| 999 | 1 | 2/1/2021 | 1 |

As you can see, the Records table provides the first 3 columns of the desired output, and the "#Opportunities" column is created by counting the number of opportunities that happen *after* the record is created for a given customer.

Two key things to note on this logic:

1. Only count opportunities when they occur within 6 months of a record.
2. If another record is created for a customer, only count opportunities for the most recent record.

More specifically, OppID = 11 will get credited to RecordID = 777; 12 to 888; and 13 to 999. 10 and 14 will not get credited to either RecordID.

I wrote the below code, which *does not* take into account #2 above:

```
CREATE TABLE #Records
(
RecordID int
, CustomerID int
, CreateDate Date
)

INSERT INTO #Records
VALUES 
(777, 1, '2021-01-01')
, (888, 2, '2021-01-31')
, (999, 1, '2021-02-01')


CREATE TABLE #Opportunities
(
OppID int
, CustomerID int
, OppCreateDate Date
)

INSERT INTO #Opportunities
VALUES 
(10, 1, '2020-12-31')
, (11, 1, '2021-01-10')
, (12, 2, '2021-02-01')
, (13, 1, '2021-04-01')
, (14, 1, '2025-08-25')

select * 
from #Records

select * 
from #Opportunities

select rec.*
, (select count(*)
from #Opportunities opp
where rec.CustomerID=opp.CustomerID
and rec.CreateDate<=opp.OppCreateDate --record happened on the same day or before the opportunity
and datediff(month,rec.CreateDate,opp.OppCreateDate) < 6 --opened and created within 6 months
) as [#Opportunities]
from #Records rec
```

Any suggestions to incorporate #2 above and generate the desired output?

Comment: isnt RecordID preventing you from getting a correct count of opportunities for that customer?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, but I am trying to count the number of opportunities for each record. Does that help clarify? Thank you!

Comment: Well it looks difficult to do so since there doesnt appear to be a relationship between records and opportunities - just customers and opportunities. Your counts will always be one right?

Comment: You are correct about no link between records and opportunities (why this is so difficult, for me at least!). The counts will not always be one. We could "add" another row to the Opportunities table with the following [start] , (15, 2, '2021-03-01') [end] Then we would have RecordID = 777 and 999 with 1 and RecordID = 888 with 2, does that make sense?

Comment: So let me get this straight - is there a primary key definition of (RecordID,CustomerID)? Because on its face what youre saying is either bad data structure design or you are leaving out details we need.

Comment: I chuckled when you mentioned bad data structure. The reason I have to crack this nut is due to that fact! Let me try explaining it this way: many records can be created for a customer; many opportunities can be created for a customer; a record is not always required to create an opportunity; when an opportunity is created, I would like to attribute that to the record that happened nearest to that opportunity's create date (as long as it was within 6 months of the [record] create date. Does that help?

Comment: Yes, and ouch that hurts lol

Comment: Also your sample data doesn't indicate that you're having any issues counting records. You would think if you're trying to get a count of records within certain time frames your sample data would indicate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide on which `#records` row is related to an `#Opportunities` row based on `#records.CreateDate`

```
select RecordID, CustomerID, CreateDate, count(*) cnt
from (
   select r.RecordID, r.CustomerID, r.CreateDate,
      row_number() over(partition by op.OppID  order by r.CreateDate desc) rn
   from #records r
   join #Opportunities op on r.CustomerID = op.CustomerID and datediff(month, r.CreateDate, op.OppCreateDate) < 6 and r.CreateDate <= op.OppCreateDate
   ) t
where rn = 1 
group by RecordID, CustomerID, CreateDate
```

Returns

```
RecordID    CustomerID  CreateDate  cnt
777 1   2021-01-01  1
888 2   2021-01-31  1
999 1   2021-02-01  1
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a stab at this. I think my original post threw you off as well. As I shared with Critical Error above, the unit of observation is the RecordID, not the CustomerID. The output should mirror what I have above in the "Desired Output" section of my original post. Does that help refine your approach? Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I've included this in my original post. It is the third table. Please let me know if you still aren't seeing it. Thank you!

Comment: I see. Can't get why 10 will not get credited to either RecordID. Why not 999  or 777?

Comment: 10 happened before both 777 and 999 (12/31/2020). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, your data, you rule. Have rewrote the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This solution makes sense and works very well for this application. I GREATLY appreciate your help with solving this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Records table ( RecordID int, CustomerID int, CreateDate date );
INSERT INTO @Records VALUES 
    ( 777, 1, '2021-01-01' ), ( 888, 2, '2021-01-31' ), ( 999, 1, '2021-02-01' );


DECLARE @Opportunities table ( OppID int, CustomerID int, OppCreateDate date );
INSERT INTO @Opportunities VALUES 
      ( 10, 1, '2020-12-31' )
    , ( 11, 1, '2021-01-10' )
    , ( 12, 2, '2021-02-01' )
    , ( 13, 1, '2021-04-01' )
    , ( 14, 1, '2025-08-25' );

SELECT
    *
FROM @Records r
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT
        COUNT ( * ) AS [#Opportunities]
    FROM @Opportunities AS o
    WHERE
        o.CustomerID = r.CustomerID
        AND o.OppCreateDate >= r.CreateDate
        AND DATEDIFF ( month, r.CreateDate, o.OppCreateDate ) <= 6
        AND o.OppID NOT IN (

            SELECT
                OppID
            FROM @Records AS r2 
            INNER JOIN @Opportunities AS o2
                ON r2.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
            WHERE
                r2.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                AND o2.OppCreateDate >= r2.CreateDate
                AND r2.RecordID > r.RecordID
        
        )

) AS Opps
ORDER BY
    r.RecordID;
```

**RETURNS**

```
+----------+------------+------------+----------------+
| RecordID | CustomerID | CreateDate | #Opportunities |
+----------+------------+------------+----------------+
|      777 |          1 | 2021-01-01 |              1 |
|      888 |          2 | 2021-01-31 |              1 |
|      999 |          1 | 2021-02-01 |              1 |
+----------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I upvoted your post as your solution appears to solve the problem that Serg was also able to address by using the "partition" function. That said, your approach is more in-line with how I was thinking about this particular problem. Great work and thanks again!!